# Assign CRS to shapefile in R

Tags: r, coordinate-system

I imported my shapefile `dat` to R with `readOGR`, coordinates are given in easting and northing, I'd like to change it to latlon and tried:

```
dat_latlon <- spTransform(dat, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
```

However, I get this error message:

```
Error in spTransform(xSP, CRSobj, ...) : 
  No transformation possible from NA reference system
```

And str(dat) shows that:

```
  ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slots
  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr NA
```

So I guess I have to assign the projection first?
Somewhere here (or stackoverflow) I found this:

```
dat@proj4string <- "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +datum=potsdam +units=m +no_defs"
```

but I only get an error:

```
Error in checkAtAssignment("SpatialPointsDataFrame", "proj4string", "character") : 
  Zuweisung eines Objektes der Klasse “character” ist für @‘proj4string’ in einem Objekt aus Klasse “SpatialPointsDataFrame” nicht zulässig; is(value, "CRS") ist nicht TRUE
```

(sorry for German - apparently it's not valid to assign an object of class character in an object of class SpatialPointsDataFrame).

Now I am stuck, can you help me?

Comment: Try `project(dat) <- CRS("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +datum=potsdam +units=m +no_defs")`

Comment: hm, this results in: `Error in project(dat) <- CRS("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +datum=potsdam +units=m +no_defs") : 
  could not find function "project<-"`

Comment: `projection(dat)`, sorry

Comment: same :/ `Error in projection(dat) <- CRS("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +datum=potsdam +units=m +no_defs") : 
  could not find function "projection<-"`

Comment: it is proj4string not projection (the latter is in raster)

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
proj4string(dat) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
```

Comment: CRS from sp library

Comment: Could you add a little more detail regarding how this fixes the problem. It may very well answer the question but short answers like these are likely to be deleted.

Comment: You do not need to call CRS, the projection description is adequate.